# Resume from an offset when program is started again

Tags: java

Before I start, this isn't your average resume from offset. Well, from what I see.
So, I have this Minecraft Server Scanner, which generates IPs from 0.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255, and I make it scan port 25565 on these IPs for a Minecraft Java server.

I want to make it so when I quit the program, it saves the value of the `offsetIPs` variable to a file name `offset.mcscan`.
Then, when the program is launched again, it will check to see if this file exists and if it does, then it will update the `for` loops to start from where it left off. Here is the code I have so far:

```
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MCScanner v" + version);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(300, 100);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent windowEvent) {
                logger.log(Level.INFO, "Stopping threads...");
                for (Thread nextThread: threadList) {
                    nextThread.interrupt();
                }
                logger.log(Level.INFO, "Making an 'offset.mcscan'...");
                try {
                    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("offset.mcscan"));
                    writer.write(Long.toString(offsetIPs));
                    writer.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Failed to write 'offset.mcscan'!");
                }
                logger.log(Level.INFO, "Exiting...");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        long scanned = 0;
        long offsetIPs = 0;

        ...

        frame.setVisible(true);

        File offsetFile = new File("offset.mcscan");
        if (offsetFile.exists()) {
            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(offsetFile));
                offsetIPs = Long.parseLong(reader.readLine());
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Failed to read 'offset.mcscan'!");
            }
        }

        // this is where I need to implement offsetIPs, but how?
        for (int i = minimumRange; i <= maxRange; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= 255; ++j) {
                for (int k = 0; k <= 255; ++k) {
                    for (int l = 0; l <= 255; ++l) {
                        String ip = i + "." + j + "." + k + "." + l;

                        ScannerThread scannerThread = new ScannerThread(ip, port, timeout, databaseHandler);
                        Thread scanThread = new Thread(scannerThread);
                        threadList.add(scanThread);
                        scanThread.start();

                        if (threadList.size() >= threads.get()) {
                            for (Thread nextThread: threadList) {
                                try {
                                    nextThread.join();
                                    ++scanned;
                                    ++offsetIPs;
                                    scannedLabel.setText("Scanned: " + scanned + "/" + progressThing * 256 + " (" + Math.round((scanned / (progressThing * 256)) * 100) / 100 + "%)");
                                } catch (InterruptedException timeout2) {
                                    // eh
                                }
                            }
                            threadList.clear();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        for (Thread nextThreadAgain: threadList) {
            try {
                nextThreadAgain.join();
                ++offsetIPs;
                ++scanned;
                // progressBar.setValue(scanned);
                scannedLabel.setText("Scanned: " + scanned + "/" + progressThing * 256);
            } catch (InterruptedException timeout1) {
                // well
            }
        }
```

Right now, I have no code for resuming from the offset.

I need it so that when it scans 64 IPs, and then I close the program, it'll write `64` to `offset.mcscan`. But now I want it to resume from that 64th IP (or whatever value is in `offset.mcscan`) (64th IP would be `1.0.0.63`), and then scan IPs after that (65th = `1.0.0.64`, 66th = `1.0.0.65`, etc).

How would I make it do this? Right now, I need help implementing it into my `for` loops. I would research, but I have no idea what I would even be searching for. I do hope this makes sense, please let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: Where are you stuck doing this? You need to use offsetIPs  (or other values you write to that file) to adjust the starting values of your loops, but you are not using it at all.

Comment: I mentioned that I'm not using it because I don't know how to implement it into the loops.

Comment: You could write i,j,k and l into your file, and initialise the loop variables from those values instead of always starting a zero.

Comment: Please post this as an answer, because it works. Thank you so much!

Comment: I think this question is too specific to be useful to other SO users, so while I'm glad my comment helped, I'm not going to write an answer.

Comment: Oh. OK. Thanks for responding anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did something like this:

```
public class MCScanner {
    private static int offsetI = 1;
    private static int offsetJ = 0;
    private static int offsetK = 0;
    private static int offsetL = 0;
    public static void main(String[] var0) {
        int thisOffsetI = offsetI;
        int thisOffsetJ = offsetJ;
        int thisOffsetK = offsetK;
        int thisOffsetL = offsetL;
        for (int i = thisOffsetI; i <= maxRange; ++i) {
            offsetI = i;
            for (int j = thisOffsetJ; j <= 255; ++j) {
                offsetJ = j;
                for (int k = thisOffsetK; k <= 255; ++k) {
                    offsetK = k;
                    for (int l = thisOffsetL; l <= 255; ++l) {
                        offsetL = l;
                        String ip = i + "." + j + "." + k + "." + l;

                        // rest of my code
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And it worked.

Explanation: I save each offset variable `offsetI/J/K/L` to `offset.mcscan`, and upon next startup, I load it and increment the offsets so that they're ready to be saved at next shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

The code in your question is not a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), however you are basically wanting to save values of certain variables to a file when your program terminates unexpectedly and when you restart your program, you want it to resume from where it failed in the previous run.

The below code removes all the unnecessary code from your question (which caused it to not compile when I copied it) and simply demonstrates what I described in the previous paragraph.

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;

public class OffsetIp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String offsetIPs;
        File offsetFile = new File("offset.mcscan");
        Path path = offsetFile.toPath();
        if (offsetFile.exists()) {
            try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(path)) {
                offsetIPs = br.readLine();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed to read 'offset.mcscan'!", e);
            }
        }
        else {
            offsetIPs = null;
        }
        int maxRange = 10;
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        int k = 0;
        int l = 0;
        if (offsetIPs != null) {
            String[] parts = offsetIPs.split("\\.");
            i = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
            j = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
            k = Integer.parseInt(parts[2]);
            l = Integer.parseInt(parts[3]);
        }
        int limit = 255;
        // this is where I need to implement offsetIPs, but how?
        for (; i <= maxRange; ++i) {
            for (; j <= limit; ++j) {
                for (; k <= limit; ++k) {
                    for (; l <= limit; ++l) {
                        offsetIPs = i + "." + j + "." + k + "." + l;
                        System.out.println(offsetIPs);
                    }
                    l = 0;
                }
                k = 0;
            }
            j = 0;
        }
        if (i >= maxRange) {
            i = 0;
        }
        if (j >= limit) {
            j = 0;
        }
        if (k >= limit) {
            k = 0;
        }
        if (l >= limit) {
            l = 0;
        }
        offsetIPs = i + "." + j + "." + k + "." + l;
        try (BufferedWriter bw = Files.newBufferedWriter(path,
                                                         StandardOpenOption.CREATE,
                                                         StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING,
                                                         StandardOpenOption.WRITE)) {
            bw.write(offsetIPs);
        }
        catch (IOException xIo) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Save failed.", xIo);
        }
    }
}
```

The above code uses [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) and [NIO.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html).
I write the last generated IP to the file. If the process terminates normally, i.e. without exceptions, then I reset the indexes so that the next time you run the code, it will start at the beginning again (which I assume is what you want). Note that inside the inner-most `for` loop – where you generate the IPs – you will probably have a `try-catch`. In that `catch` block you also need to write the last generated IP to the file. Also note that you probably need to change the `catch` blocks, in the above code, to better suit your needs (which I could not ascertain from your question).

Answer (score 0):

Store the address within a class, so that you can increment it accordingly.
Subsequently, you can use a *toString* to return the text representation.

```java
class Address {
    long value;

    Address(long value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    void increment() {
        value++;
    }
    
    void increment(long amount) {
        value += amount;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        long value = this.value;
        StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();
        for (int count = 0; count < 4; count++) {
            if (count != 0) string.insert(0, '.');
            string.insert(0, value & 0xff);
            value >>= 8;
        }
        return string.toString();
    }
}
```

Here is an example usage.

```java
Address address = new Address(0x0100003f);
address.increment();
System.out.println(address);
```

Output

```
1.0.0.64
```

You could then utilize *save* and *load* methods to maintain the offset.

```java
Address load() throws FileNotFoundException {
    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("offset.mcscan"))) {
        return new Address(scanner.nextLong());
    }
}

void save(Address address) throws IOException {
    try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("offset.mcscan")) {
        writer.write(String.valueOf(address.value));
    }
}
```

Example,

```java
Address address = new Address(0x0100003f);
save(address);
address = load();
address.increment();
System.out.println(address);
```

Output

```
1.0.0.64
```

Comment: I actually might use a bit of this for my code. Thank you for answering, anyway!